# Creating spark cluster with drone.yml not working

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, janusgraph, drone.io

I have docker-compose.yml with below image and configuration

```
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
```

here the docker-compose up log  --->   https://jpst.it/1Xc4K

and here containers up and running and i mean spark worker connected to spark master without any issues , now problem is i created drone.yml and where i added services component with

```
services:
  jce-cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.0
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"

  jce-elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:5.6.16-alpine
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

  janusgraph:
    image: janusgraph/janusgraph:latest
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
    environment:
      JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cassandra-es
      janusgraph.storage.backend: cql
      janusgraph.storage.hostname: jce-cassandra
      janusgraph.index.search.backend: elasticsearch
      janusgraph.index.search.hostname: jce-elastic
    depends_on:
      - jce-elastic
      - jce-cassandra

  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark

  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
```

but here spark worker is not connected to spark master getting exceptions, [here](https://onlinenotepad.us/pRy3mPmkBF) is exception log details , can some one please guide me why am facing this issue

Note : I am trying to create these services in drone.yml for my integration testing

Comment: any one here to help please

Comment: maybe the master service is not ready as the worker connects. for testing purpose add command: sleep 10  in your worker service .

Comment: can you also post your `drone.yml` file, please?

Comment: @leachim742 , spark worker has depends-on tag , please check , so spark worker will wait for spark master and i am seeing that during build

Comment: @Bravo a depends-on will not wait until the other container is ready , it is just start the master before the salve , check my comments and answer in the linked question

Comment: @LinPy  in the above services defination , can you guide me how to add sleep command , because in since we added environment section , if we add command drone is giving error , so can you please me the configuration how to add

Comment: the correct way is not to use sleep , you should use https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 0):

Answering for better formatting. The comments suggest sleeping. Assuming this is the dockerfile (https://hub.docker.com/r/bde2020/spark-worker/dockerfile) You could sleep by adding the command:

```
  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    command: sleep 10 && /bin/bash /worker.sh
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
```

Although sleep 10 is probably excessive, if this would would `sleep 5` or `sleep 2`