# how to get and set the ip address of one container in another docker image config?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have below sample docker-compose yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - SPARK_CONTAINDER_IP = **here i want the ip address of above spark master**
```

is it possible? can anyone please help me

**Update :**  we can get container ID using below command

```
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}" --filter "dockerhost"
```

but am not getting use this command return values and assign it to environment variable

Comment: why do you need the IP address? you can use service name and compose will resolve it for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232036/creating-spark-cluster-with-drone-yml-not-working   here if you see i tried what you mentioned , but it is not working now i want to use actual IP address , to see if it will work

Comment: your another compose works just fine, maybe your worker started faster than your master therefore you get the exceptions , see https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: I got this using your compose : 19/12/10 11:03:25 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark-master/172.19.0.2:7077 after 348 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)

Comment: with docker-compose yml it is working , please check question , am configuring in drone.yml for integrating testing , their during drone build it is giving error

Comment: @LinPy , if you see worker will try for the connection multiple times (by the time spark master up and running in my case) still am getting the issue

Comment: I test the files with the 5 services in it ....

Comment: @LinPy  in .drone.yml ?

Comment: yes but I do not use drone :) just compose up

Comment: with compose it is working for me , am facing issue with .drone.ym

Answer (score 0):

as I said in the comments:

> your another compose works just fine, maybe your worker started faster
>   than your master therefore you get the exceptions , see
>   docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order

other solution could be use fix IP adresses in your compose for your services:

```
myservice:
    container_name: mycon
    image: some:image
    networks:
       mynet:
          ipv4_address: 172.28.1.10

networks:
    mynet:
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

Comment: i have no permission to create  custom networks in drone build in my case